# Show/Hide Image Button issues in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make show/hide type of button that toggles all the images on page on and off. I try to do it with `getElementsByClassName`. 
First, I used this:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('showHide').style.visibility ='visible')
{
 document.getElementsByClassName('showHide').style.visibility == 'hidden' 
}
```

But I got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visibility' of undefined` error. So I changed the code to:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('showHide');
for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++){
    if (elems[i].style.visibility == 'visible')
    {
        elems[i].style.visibility == 'hidden' 
    }
}
```

And now I got nothing. No errors, but button doesn't work. I'm learning js just now, but I don't know where's the problem. Also, I really would like to try avoid jQuery or any other framework if possible.

Whole code looks like that:

```
<head>
<title>Button Test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showImage()
    {
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('showHide');
        for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++)
            {
                if (elems[i].style.visibility == 'visible')
                {
                    elems[i].style.visibility == 'hidden' 
                }
                else (elems[i].style.visibility == 'hidden')
                {
                    elems[i].style.visibility == 'visible'
                }
            }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top">
    <input type="button" value="Pokaż/Ukryj Grafikę" id="showHideButton" onclick="showImage();"/>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <div class="topSide showHide">
        <img src="IMG/1.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="topSide showHide">
        <img src="IMG/2.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="topSide showHide">
        <img src="IMG/3.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

All and any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, `else` clauses do not take conditions. Second, you are using comparison operators when you want to assign values. So, the correct code is as follows:

```
function showImage()
    {
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('showHide');
        for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++)
            {
                if (elems[i].style.visibility == 'visible')
                {
                    elems[i].style.visibility = 'hidden' 
                }
                else
                {
                    elems[i].style.visibility = 'visible'
                }
            }
    }
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

Something that's also worth noting is that your element does not have any visibility defined at the first button click, so `elems[i].style.visibility` will come as '' (empty string) at first. So you'd want to add `style="visibility: visible"` to each div with `.showHide` class OR alter the `if` clause from:

```
if (elems[i].style.visibility == 'visible')
```

to:

```
if (elems[i].style.visibility == 'visible' || elems[i].style.visibility == '')
```

for your code to work flawlessly as it is.

Comment: Thank You so much! Fixing up `else` took care of the problem. (tried to upvote the answer but not enough rep:/)

Comment: Only selecting this answer as your chosen is already enough if it helped you. :)

Comment: Yes, see my answer's "important note". It solves exactly this problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using a comparison `==` when you should be using an assignment `=`, like this:

```
if (elems[i].style.visibility == 'visible')  // comparison
{
    elems[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';    // assignment
}
```

Comment: Changed it as per Your suggestion but to no avail :( Still nothing. But hey, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things are wrong.

Your 2nd attempt was nearly correct, just the assignment is wrong (only one `=` in assignments)

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('showHide');
for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++){
    if (elems[i].style.visibility == 'visible')
    {
        elems[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

In the full code, there's another problem... your `else` clause looks like it meant to be an `else if` (And again, wrong assignment)

```
else if (elems[i].style.visibility == 'hidden')
{
   elems[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, else clauses don't have conditions, and also assignments only have single = signs. Also, visibility is initialized to "" so you must include a check for that. Here is corrected code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Button Test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showImage()
    {
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('showHide');
        for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++)
        {
            if (elems[i].style.visibility == 'visible' || elems[i].style.visibility == "")
            {
                elems[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
            else if(elems[i].style.visibility == 'hidden')
            {
                elems[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top">
    <input type="button" value="Pokaż/Ukryj Grafikę" id="showHideButton" onclick="showImage();"/>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <div class="topSide showHide">
        <img src="IMG/1.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="topSide showHide">
        <img src="IMG/2.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="topSide showHide">
        <img src="IMG/3.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```